# Panel Vector Autoregression with Endogenous Binary Variable

Tags: stata, binary-data, logit, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

I want to estimate a Panel Vector Autoregression model (bivariate), while one of my variables is binary. Hence I have to estimate a VAR model with one linear equation and one logistic equation.
Any tips with which software I could realize this and how? (Preferrably Stata)

Comment: I think it might be more rewarding to ask this on the Stata list?